# How can I print list as row

Tags: python

How can I print:

```
['12', '567', '32']
```

like

```
12
567
32
```

I tried pd.DataFrame but it gives row numbers i dont want that

Comment: Index into the list. The simplest way, beginner-friendly:

    name_of_variable = ['12', '567', '32']
    
    print(name_of_variable[0])
    print(name_of_variable[1])
    print(name_of_variable[2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline character `\n` prints a new line:

```
l = [12, 567, 32]
print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in l))
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote something wrong I just edited can u look again?

Comment: @jetrldz My code still works with your edit

Comment: oh thanks a lot I just tried it